# Mock the global window object in require.js

Tags: window, mocking, requirejs

1. I have a web application that uses window.applicationCache for
   offline access.
2. All of my code that manages the appCache
   (eg. checking/updating/swapping the cache) is encapsulated into a
   "cache-controller" object.
3. I have unit tests to test my
   "cache-controller" functions. For testing, I temporarily
   replace the native window.applicationCache object with my own mock
   version (since I only want to test *my* code, not the browsers
   appCache implementation), eg.

   ```
   window.applicationCache = { /* my appCache mock */ };
   // unit tests run here. Code under test references window.applicationCache.
   ```

A while ago (circa. Chrome 16) this approach worked perfectly. Then Chrome 17, on both Mac & Windows platforms, removed the ability to patch over the browser's default window.applicationCache property (while curiously, it still works fine in Chrome for Linux for all versions up to and including Chrome 26). At the time, I [logged a Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=106814) for this; but unfortunately that bug report is still listed as 'unconfirmed'.

Anyway, I've just ported my application from traditional 'browser globals' (ie. loading *.js files via script tags; all JS objects are global) to AMD-style modules, using [require.js](http://requirejs.org) as the module loader.

One of the benefits of AMD (or CommonJS) is dependency-injection, where your code gets a **local reference** to any dependent objects, rather than relying on a global reference, eg.

```
require(['foo'], function(Foo) {
  var bar = new Foo();
});
```

...which makes it easy to do object mocking, since you can configure the module loader to pass a mock object for 'foo' when in test mode.

I had hoped that by moving to dependency-injection, I could get around my applicationCache issue (as the 'window' reference passed into my modules could be either the global window object, or a mock object).

However I'm not sure how to have require.js inject 'window' as a dependency into my modules?

Is it possible (perhaps using a [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)?) to define a 'window' module; which can then be passed to any code that operates on the global 'window' object?  So that I could do something like this:

```
require(['???'], function(window) {
  // 'window' here is the real window object, or for testing it's a mock window object
  window.applicationCache.update();
});
```

...where '???' is a module name that refers to the window object.

Or would I need to define my own module that exports 'window', which could mapped differently for unit testing, eg.

```
// window.js
define(function() {
  return window;  // real global window object
});

// window-mock.js
define(function() {
  return {
    applicationCache: { /* mock version of appCache */ }
  }
});

// for unit testing, remap 'window' to the mock version
require.config({
  map: {
    "cache-controller": {
      "window": "window-mock"
    }
  }
});

// cache-controller.js
require(['window'], function(window) {
  window.applicationCache.update();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answered my own question.  I decided to create the window.js and window-mock.js modules as described above, which allowed me to pass the mock version when running unit tests, and use the 'real' window object when running normally.